# Why does the index column's title not show when using StyleFrame sf.to_excel()?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, indexing, styleframe

I am writing a script in which I want the output to be an Excel sheet with auto-fitted column width's. Further, I want the index column's title to appear.

Right now, I run the script and the Excel sheet populates with auto-fitted column width's, but the index column's title does not appear. Is there a quick 
fix for this?

```
for type in tickers:
    df5 = pd.DataFrame(df4.diff(periods=1, axis=0))
    frames = [df4.iloc[-2,:],df4.iloc[-1,:],df5.iloc[-1,:]]
    df6 = pd.concat(frames, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
    df6 = round(df6, 2)
    df6.columns = ["Last Week ($mm/bp)", "This Week ($mm/bp)", "Change ($mm/bp)"]
    df6.index.name = "{}".format(type)
    df6 = df6.reindex(index = ["ED1 Comdty", "TU1 Comdty", "FV1 Comdty", "TY1 Comdty", "UXY1 Comdty", "US1 Comdty", "WN1 Comdty", "Total"])
    sf = StyleFrame(df6)
    sf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=type, index=True)
    writer.save()
```

[image: StyleFrame Output]

Comment: There is not an easy workaround, but it will be fixed in next version

Comment: This is fixed in the latest version (1.6.1)